# Windows form: Focus and Show doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MultiThreaded pplication with many Controls and forms. I have an event regeistered that will call Show Method on a form to show. When the event occur for the first time it executes the method Show but the form is not shown but now if event fires again(2nd, 3rd, ....) the form is shown.

I am making a simple call `frm.Show()`.

---

2nd Problem

In my next application the same thing happen bu instead of show the Focus doesnt work for the first time.
I have tried the following properties :

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Focus();
//this.BringToFront();
this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: That you call Show() of Form and you don't see it is already bad. Could be as you call Show() and not ShowDialog() it appears behind your main window, so you just don't see it?

Comment: could you please post some code snippet showing your call of the Show method?  In which thread this method is called?

Comment: more code please! its kind ah tough to give any opinions with just these snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling Show() from a different thread than the one in which the form was created? In general Windows Forms Controls are not thread safe and behavior is unpredictable. There are a few ways to do it though if you must. I recommend you read this MSDN article on how to make thread-safe calls: [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls To Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)